# How to properly phrase it "Archive 3 recent days"

Tags: phrase-request

I've been thinking how to phrase a sentence. I meant to say we will back up a copy daily. If today is Thursday, we have an archive of Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday. If today is Sunday, we have a copy of Thurs, Fri and Sat.

Does any of the following sound appropriate?

> Daily backup and archive ***up to 3 recent days***

> Daily backup and archive ***the last 3 days***

I think the first sentence construction is not right. I googled but I don't see any sentence examples using *numbers* before *recent days*.

I'm not too sure if the second sentence is conveying the meaning correctly.

I'm cracking my brain not sure how to phrase the sentence correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would rephrase "Daily backup" to "Backup daily" since the more common construction of a command is verb + adverb, not the other way around. "Daily backup" is too easily read as a noun--which it is--as in, "Have you done your daily backup today?"

Second, **up to 3 recent days** is not idiomatic, which is why you don't find examples in your Google search. To improve the first example, you could write:

> Backup daily and archive the three most recent days.

The second example is better, and will work fine if you simply reverse "daily" and "backup":

> Backup daily and archive [or *keep an archive of*] the last three days.

Answer (score 0):

I have upvoted Rob Jarvis’s answer. However, if we go beyond the original question of what is “proper” into what will most easily be understood by the most people, I would change the vocabulary.

Make a back-up copy daily and keep it until four days after it was made.